# Need to set up a GUI that shows output from Pocketsphinx on Raspberry Pi 2 using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, pocketsphinx

I need to set up a GUI that simply shows the output of Pocketsphinx on Raspberry Pi. I have installed Pocketsphinx and can run it from command line, but am not quite clear on how to set up the GUI. I have been using Python 2.7,  and have seen online that others have tried importing it? Please help me figure this out.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is [pocketsphinx wrapper for python](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python).